# Removing html class drupal7 starter-theme

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I'm kinda new to drupal and are currently just making a fresh theme folder, but i have a problem. I have edited my page.tpl.php and .info file to suit my page. But when I edit the page I dont get the entire page, which I want. Sorry if im not clear, but there is nothing named like this in any of my files -

```
<html class="js" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" dir="ltr" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" xml:lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
```

I was looking at the page elements and found this which is like a border around the entire page so my own page doesn't go all the way to the edges which looks bad. I have 2 pictures here so you can see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FjQl.png

What I want is that my root div expands all the way to the edge, and I dont know how to do it currently since I cant fine that html-class anywhere!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The line with the opening HTML tag can be found in modules/system/html.tpl.php.

If you copy that file to your theme folder then you can edit it there and that copy of it will override the one in the system module.

From your pictures it looks like there is padding on either the body on the div with ID root.

Inspect both of these elements and see which had padding on it. Then you can create a new rule in your themes CSS file to remove the padding.